Using AssemblyFixture in SpecFlow: How to Initialize Fixture Once for Multiple Feature Files
I have been attempting to utilize AssemblyFixture in SpecFlow to initialize the fixture only once for all the SpecFlow tests spanning multiple feature files. Could anyone share an example of how I can accomplish this?  I tried below code, but when I run the specflow tests MyAssemblyFixture being created multiple times. But it is expected to create only once. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.
[assembly: AssemblyFixture(typeof(MyAssemblyFixture))]
public class MyAssemblyFixture : IDisposable
{
    public static int InstantiationCount;

    public MyAssemblyFixture()
    {
        InstantiationCount++;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
    }
}

[Binding]
public class Steps
{
    public Steps(MyAssemblyFixture fixture)
    {
        
    }

    [Then(@"the expected result should be (.*)")]
    public void ThenTheExpectedResultShouldBe(int p0)
    {
        Assert.Equal(1, MyAssemblyFixture.InstantiationCount);
    }
}

Feature1.feature
 Feature: Feature1 

    Scenario: My Scenarion 1
        Then the expected result should be 1

Feature2.feature
Feature: Feature2 
 
Scenario: My Scenarion 2
    Then the expected result should be 1


Can you [edit] your question to include information about how you are running these tests? From Visual Studio? From the command line via dotnet test?

Ok, and when it runs more than once, how often does it run? Once per test? Once per test run? Once per group of tests?
